# Passing values in a view from controller after getting those values from same view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. I want to get "fromDate" and "ToDate" from a view. In the same view, I need three DropDownLists that are empty and hidden.

After clicking on the submit button, those DropDownLists should be visible and filled with data based on the dates picked.

But I am getting 'null reference' error on view page.

**My View Page is**

```
<h2>View Data in Database</h2>
<table><tr><td>
@using(Html.BeginForm("ViewPage1","Home"))
{
   <table><tr><td>From Date:</td>
              <td>@html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FromDate,"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>To Date:</td>
              <td>@html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ToDate,"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><input type="submit" Value="Show"></td>
              <td><input type="submit" Value="Show"></td>
          </tr>
   </table>
   <div id="ShowDropBoxes">
   <table>
        <tr><td>@Html.CheckBox("Production Order:", new{id="ck1"})</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownlistFor(m=>m.ProdNo, Model.ProdOrdList, "Select Production Order")</td>
        </tr>
         <tr><td>@Html.CheckBox("Part Number:", new{id="ck2"})</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownlistFor(m=>m.PartNo, Model.PartNoList, "Select Part Number")</td>
        </tr>
         <tr><td>@Html.CheckBox("Status:", new{id="ck3"})</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownlistFor(m=>m.StatusTxt, Model.StatusList, "Select Status")</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
```

**My Model is**

```
  public class HomeModel
  {
      public DateTime FromDate {get; set; }
      public DateTime ToDate {get; set; }
      public string ProdNo {get; set; }
      public string PartNo {get; set; }
      public int status {get; set; }
      public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList ProdNoList {get; set; }
      public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList PartNoList {get; set; }
      public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList StatusList {get; set; }
  }
```

**Controller Is:-**

```
  public class HomeController: Controller
  {
       Repository List_in_Repository = new Repository();

       public ActionResult ViewPage1()
       {
           return View();
       }
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult ViewPage(HomeModel model)
       {
             string fromdate = model.FromDate.Tostring("yyyyMMdd");
             string todate = model.ToDate.Tostring("yyyyMMdd");
             model.ProdNoList = new SelectList(List_in_Repository.GetProductionOrders(fromdate,todate));
             model.PartNoList= new SelectList(List_in_Repository.GetPartNumbers(fromdate,todate));
             model.StatusList = new SelectList(List_in_Repository.GetStatus(fromdate,todate));
            return View(model);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Write this at end of ViewPage return View(model); in HttPost method

Comment: Where you are getting  'null reference' ? Also where is return view() in httppost?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/2756409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GET method does not initialize the `SelectList`'s for properties `ProdNoList`, `PartNoList` and `StatusList` so when you attempt to access them in `@Html.DropDownlistFor(m => m.ProdNo, Model.ProdOrdList ...)` the exception is thrown.

You GET method will need to add initialize these using empty lists (for example using `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`)

Its not clear how you are 'hiding' the dropdown lists when you initially display he view, but you should consider a view model property say (`bool DisplayDropDowns` which you set to `true` in the POST method before returning the view. Then you could check the value using

```
@if(Model.DisplayDropDowns)
{
  .... // render dropdowns
}
```

This would mean the `SelectList`'s would not need to be initialized in the GET method since the code inside the `if` block will never be executed.

Note also that the POST method should include `return View(model);`

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen , You are really awesome ...!!